# How to search list of IDs within a hashed list of IDs

Tags: java, algorithm, aws-lambda

I have a list of around 1 million ids(ID set A). A subset of those ids, are constantly moved to a new data store in ID Set B, but before being stored in Set B, they are seed hashed (let's say with SHA256). Sometimes ID from Set A get dropped, and hence every 30 days I need to check if the Set B ids are still valid and exist in Set A.

Problem is that I cannot simply take Set B  and check against Set A, as Set B is hashed. I guess checking each ID in Set A with  Set B might not be efficient too.

What might be some efficient ways to solve this? I can choose to consider another hashing technique for Set B if it helps.

Comment: Can you keep a parallel set of hashed IDs?

Comment: Can you hash Set A and just compare the hashes?

Comment: Can you extend Set A by keeping a state (active/dropped) and date modified? If IDs in Set A are not actually removed but just marked as "dropped" you can query and compare the relevant entries only.